# Faster ways to transfer results from a dataframe to SQL Server?

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, dataframe, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to upload 13,000 rows to a SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.5893) using Python.

It takes about three minutes, which seems unreasonably long, and I'm sure it could be done faster. I am using SQLAlchemy. Is there a faster way?

```
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=......;DATABASE=.....")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
try:
    print ('uploading...')
    dataFrame.to_sql("MyTable", schema='dbo', con=engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=1000)
```

Comment: Python is great for simplicity, but unfortunately doesn't perform very well when it comes to moving data into SQL. If you really want to speed things up, you probably want to persist the data to a file and use something like [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) (perhaps using something like `subprocess.run` if you want to stick with python) or [SQL Bulk Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Rightyo, that's good to know, thanks.

Comment: Agreed that you can't beat the `bcp` utility for speed, but its flexibility leaves a bit to be desired, e.g.: it doesn't support RFC4180 format CSV files where field data may contain delimiter, line break and/or qualifier characters. If you're on SQL Server 2017 or later, though, (and your version indicates that you're on 2019) you can handle those files using `BULK INSERT` from SQL Server itself.

Comment: To stick with Python, have you tried: `DRIVER={SQL Server};` requests use of the legacy SQL Server Native Client driver which hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012 days, you could try `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` (or 18, depending on which you have installed). The SQLAlchemy 1.3 release in 2019 added support for a [fast_executemany option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_13.html#dialect-improvements-and-changes-sql-server). The Pandas [to_sql method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) has a `method='multi'` option.

Comment: I thought `DRIVER={SQL Server}` that was what I was doing in my SQL code. The method='multi' I can try.